# Single else clause for multiple if clauses - javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

First: I'm JavaScript newbie.
So.. I have basic form with password, repeat password, email and repeat email fields. I want to check if password is equal to repeat password. If it's not, alert message appears and page reloads. Same for email and repeat email.
BUT if pass and repeat password aren't equal AND email and repeat email aren't equal, first alert message appears, then the second message (this time for email) appears too fast. I want to show only one alert message when both fields don't match.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           function checkFields() {
            var pass= document.getElementById('password');
            var reppass= document.getElementById('reppass');

            var email= document.getElementById('email');
            var repemail= document.getElementById('repemail');

            if (pass.value != reppass.value) {
               alert('Passwords dont match');
               window.location.reload();
            }

            if (email.value != repemail.value) {
                alert('Emails dont match');
                window.location.reload();
            }                   

            else if (pass.value != reppass.value && email.value != repemail.value) {
                alert('Both fields dont match');
                window.location.reload();
            }

        }   

  </script>
```

And the form:

```
<form onSubmit="checkFields()">
<p><label>Password:</label> <input name="password" id="password" required="true" type="password" /></p>
<p><label>Repeat password:</label> <input name="reppass" id="reppass" required="true" type="password" /></p> 
<p><label>Email:</label> <input name="email" id="email" required="true" type="email" /></p>
<p><label>Repeat Email:</label> <input name="repemail" id="repemail" required="true" type="email" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return from the if clauses like this:

```
function checkFields() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
    var reppass = document.getElementById('reppass');

    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var repemail = document.getElementById('repemail');

    if (pass.value != reppass.value && email.value != repemail.value) {
        alert('Both fields dont match');
        window.location.reload();
    }

    if (pass.value != reppass.value) {
        alert('Passwords dont match');
        window.location.reload();
        return;
    }

    if (email.value != repemail.value) {
        alert('Emails dont match');
        window.location.reload();
        return;
    }

}
```

I like this style, because it prevents nesting if clauses. The downside is, that you have multiple return points that can be confusing - this heavily depends on the length of the function.

**EDIT**

Updated order of if blocks

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the third if statement will never evaluate to true since you're already checking those values and then returning.

Comment: Shouldn't the third statement come first? That way, if it finds both don't match it will return that?

Answer (score 1):

```
if( condition1 ) {
}else if( condition2 ) {
}else{
    …
}
```

I believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to break the validation up into separate methods, then only run the second validation if the first one succeeds.

Here's an example:

```
var FormValiditor = function() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
    var reppass = document.getElementById('reppass');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var repemail = document.getElementById('repemail');

    return {
        checkFields: function() {
            if(checkPassword()){
             return checkEmail();   
            }
            return false;
        },
        checkPassword: function() {
            if (pass.value != reppass.value) {
                alert("Password don't match");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
        checkEmail: function() {
            if(email.value != repemail.value){
              alert("Emails do not match");
              return false  
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}();
```

Then, if you're using jQuery(which you should be!) you can run validation when the form gets submitted.

`$('form').submit(FormValidator.checkFields);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ...
else if ...
else if ...
...
else ...
```

That's how it should be structured. You can have as many `else if`s as you like.